# as vs like (both mean looking like here)

Tags: prepositions

Consider:

> They were all dressed as clowns.
>
> The bomb was disguised as a package.

If I replaced "as" with "like", what would it bring any difference in meaning? Would it be acceptable in conversation? Both would act as subject complement here.

I couldn't give any other complicated examples than this, which might make it more tricky to answer, but I guess there must be some.

Comment: *like* means like! *as* means what it is! So, if you dress like a clown, your appearance is *like* a clown but if you dress *as* a clown, you *are* clown.

Comment: I don't think so. The second example better defines it as "like".

Comment: Like I said, Some other examples would make things even more complicated.

Comment: To me, *like* is a bit more ambiguous than *as*. In both sentences, with *as*, I would that them as a hint that they were dressed or the bomb was disguised intentionally. With *like*, it could mean the same thing, or it could be something perceived by a third person; that is, to this third person, their appearances were clown-like, and the bomb looked like a package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: These are not strict rules. They are interchangeable, but usually will hold these meanings.

*As* implies they are wearing clown attire.

> They were all dressed as clowns with big red noses and over-sized pants.

*Like* implies they may be wearing something that looks goofy or resembles a clown, without actually wearing clown attire.

> They were dressed like clowns in their unorthodox clothes.

With your bomb sentence, *as* and *like* convey a very similar meaning. When using *as*, you are saying the bomb literally looks like a package. When you use *like*, the bomb has characteristics that it shares with a package, but can be differentiated from a package. For example, the bomb may have a cardboard exterior like a package, but has buttons on top for timing the bomb as well.

Comment: the same thing I said in my comment (about the dressing)!